# Reading a csv-file with pandas.read_csv and an index creates NaN entries

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

My .csv-file is comma separated, which is the standard setting from read_csv.

This is working:

```
T1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(loggerfile, header = 2)) #header contains column "1"
```

But as soon as I add something to `DataFrame`'s constructor besides the `read_csv`, all my values are suddenly `NaN`.
Why? How to solve this?

```
datetimeIdx = pd.to_datetime( T1["1"] )                #timestamp-column
T2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(loggerfile, header = 2), index = datetimeIdx)
```

Answer (score 12):

It's not necessary to wrap `read_csv` in a `DataFrame` call, as it already returns a `DataFrame`.

If you want to change the index, you can use `set_index` or directly set the index:

```
T1 = pd.read_csv(loggerfile, header = 2)
T1.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(T1["1"])
```

If you want to keep the column in the dataframe as a datetime (and not string):

```
T1 = pd.read_csv(loggerfile, header = 2)
T1["1"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(T1["1"])
T2 = T1.set_index("1", drop=False)
```

But even better, you can do this directly in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) (assuming the column "1" is the first column):

```
pd.read_csv(loggerfile, header=2, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

---

The reason it returns a DataFrame with `NaNs` is because the `DataFrame()` call with a DataFrame as input will do a `reindex` operation with the provided input. As none of the labels in `datetimeIdx` are in the original index of `T1` you get a dataframe with all NaNs.

Comment: Is this answer possibly connected to another question of me?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655667/dataframe-correlation-produces-nan-although-its-values-are-all-integers

And is it possible to keep the index-col as a copy in the dataframe?

Comment: My first suggestion (setting the index directly) will keep the column in the dataframe

Comment: @user2366975  See that gray checkmark up and to the left? You might think about clicking it.