# NaN values occurring in `df.corr()`

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and new to python in general. I have been tasked with matching some products from our database. I was following a step-by-step process written [here](https://practicaldatascience.co.uk/machine-learning/how-to-create-a-product-matching-model-using-xgboost).
But I got stuck on a instruction that says correlate the dataframe. I am getting `NaN` values here. The 1st two pictures are the same dataframe I want to operate `corr` on. Third one is the result. Can I get some guidance here, please?

`datafreame_pic1`:
[image: datafreame_pic1]

`datafreame_pic2`:
[image: datafreame_pic2]

`result_of_df.corr()`:
[image: result_of_df.corr()]

Comment: if the column in match is all 1s, correlation will give u NA because there is no deviation

Comment: avoid pasting images of tables and provide the code please, like how you obtained the last data frame before the correlation. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: to get the last dataframe before the correlation, I had to pass my original dataframe through a series of jellyfish functions all of which are written on the instruction on this site https://practicaldatascience.co.uk/machine-learning/how-to-create-a-product-matching-model-using-xgboost @StupidWolf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered before [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22657319/8653046)

Here is the definition of correlation between two variables (`i` and `j` being the elements of each variable):

```
cor(i,j) = cov(i,j)/[stdev(i)*stdev(j)]
```

If the values of the `i`th or `j`th variable do not vary (in your case they are all 1, so they are not really changing), then the respective standard deviation will be zero and so will the denominator of the fraction. Thus, the correlation will be `NaN`.

If you try the following, you will get all `NaN` values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(16).reshape(4,4))
```

[image]

```
dataframe.corr()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to be the problem.