# I do not understand why am i getting Nan value in corrwith() when there is no null value in either of the dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I created 2 dataframes called "ee" and "dd" and tried to find the  correlation between them using corrwith() ,i can't figure out why am i  getting NaN value in the result.

```
    import pandas as pd

    # DataFrame dd values
    dd_data = {
        'TOT_SALES': [7.9, 6.8, 8.8, 3.9, 24.2, 4.9, 83.0, 69.8, 44.7, 35.4, 71.2, 61.4, 
    53.8],
        'nCustomers': [2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 16, 12, 11, 9, 12, 9, 9],
        'nTxnPerCust': [1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0625, 1.0000, 
    1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000],
'nChipsPerTxn': [1.500000, 1.500000, 2.000000, 1.000000, 1.750000, 1.000000, 1.562500, 1.666667, 1.454545, 1.222222, 1.666667, 1.666667, 1.777778],
'avgPricePerUnit': [2.633333, 2.266667, 4.400000, 3.900000, 3.457143, 2.450000, 3.320000, 3.490000, 2.793750, 3.218182, 3.560000, 4.093333, 3.362500]
    }

    dd_index = pd.to_datetime(['1801', '1802', '1803', '1804', '1805', '1806', '1807', '1808', '1809', '1810', '1811', '1812', '1901'])

   dd = pd.DataFrame(dd_data, index=dd_index)

    # DataFrame ee values
    ee_data = {
'TOT_SALES': [14.3, 8.7, 15.7, 16.6, 17.2, 7.6, 38.8, 41.9, 59.6, 54.3, 49.2, 51.6, 60.2],
'nCustomers': [3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 9, 10, 12, 11, 9, 9, 15],
'nTxnPerCust': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
'nChipsPerTxn': [1.333333, 1.0, 1.666667, 2.0, 1.25, 2.0, 1.555556, 1.3, 1.5, 1.454545, 1.555556, 1.444444, 1.333333],
'avgPricePerUnit': [3.575000, 4.350000, 3.140000, 4.150000, 3.440000, 3.800000, 2.771429, 3.223077, 3.311111, 3.393750, 3.514286, 3.969231, 3.010000]
   }

    ee_index = pd.to_datetime(['1801', '1802', '1803', '1804', '1805', '1806', '1807', '1808', '1809', '1810', '1811', '1812', '1901'])

    ee = pd.DataFrame(ee_data, index=ee_index)

    # Correlation calculation
    correlation = dd.corrwith(ee, axis=0)

    print(correlation)
```

THE RESULT COMING

```
    TOT_SALES          0.773883
    nCustomers         0.811135
    nTxnPerCust             NaN
    nChipsPerTxn      -0.542081
    avgPricePerUnit   -0.235673
    dtype: float64
```

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that `ee_data`, `nTxnPerCust` contains all the same number 1.0. If you change one of these into let's say 10.0 you will get an answer. Obviously no correlation can be found between ee and dd, when all numbers are the same in one of the data frames. See also: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html

Comment: Possibly you want the correlation over the columns in that case you have to do `correlation = dd.corrwith(ee, axis=1)`

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22657319/18571565) which explains how correlation is calculated.  When standard deviation is zero, correlation will be nan as it is dividing by zero.

Comment: so its not a code error,thanks Rawson